# Not able to display Kal UI in application

Tags: objective-c, ios7, kal

I am having trouble displaying the `Kal calendar UI` in my application. Actually the calendar is being displayed but everything is very dark. I have a tabbed bar application and i am not using storyboards. I have upgraded to Xcode 5.

Here's what I should get:

[image]

And Here's what i am getting:

[image]

Here's what i have done so far: I have copied all the classes in the Kal api into my code. when the fourth tab of my `UITabBarController` is pressed, the calendar needs to show up. The `UIViewController` associated with the 4th tab is `MonthlyTabBarItemViewController.`

**MonthlyTabBarItemViewController.h**

```
#import "KalViewController.h"
@interface MonthlyTabBarItemViewController : UIViewController<KalDataSource>
@end
```

**MonthlyTabBarItemViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    KalViewController *kal = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:kal.view];
}
```

These steps should at least show the calendar UI properly.. right?? Why am i getting everything dark?

Someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the graphics aren't being found/used, as though you haven't included the `Kal.bundle` into your project? Within the bundle is all of the graphics that Kal uses to display correctly in a view. If you include that to your project and link it up in the same way as the rest of the Kal project, it should find the graphics okay and display as you expect.